# Java tip calculator

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator

Basically I just need help with a tip calculator program. It should ask how many customers there are, the tip percentage to be used, the bill amount of each customer, the tip amount, and the tip amount distributed evenly to each customer. I'm also trying to get the program to read in as many customers as the user wants to input for bonus to the homework. Here is the code, instead of the program returning "Please enter their bill amount" i keep getting "Is there another customer? y or n?". That is the main problem i'm having. Excuse the bad structuring, i'm basically a complete beginner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class H3_TipCalc {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter your bill amount.");
      double bill = input.nextDouble();
      { 
         String multiplecust = ("Y");

         //int mc = 1;
         while (multiplecust.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
         {
            Scanner usrin = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Is there another customer? y or n?");
            multiplecust = usrin.nextLine();
            //mc++; 
            if (usrin.equals("y"))
            {
               System.out.println("Please enter their bill amount.");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (usrin.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter their bill amount.");
    }
```

You're comparing the `Scanner` to `"y"`, which is probably not what you want to compare. Compare `multiplecust` to `"y"`.